# Missing XPath in Windows Metro App

Tags: c#, xpath, windows-8

Is there an easy way to perform XPath query's on XML in a Windows 8 metro app? `System.Xml.XPath` does not exist in the .NET framework used to create metro apps and after trying to use the HTMLAgilityPack I haven't been able to make any progress either.

Are there an easy way to perform these query's?

Comment: When writing a title, don't just list tags. Try to put a very short description of the problem you are facing. That makes it easier to find later, and people can get a sense of what you are having difficulties with before clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but you could try and leverage
System.XML.Linq which provides access to XDocument, XElement, XName, XNode, XContainer etc and Parse methods for each.  See an example of using queries and using the classes in System.XML and System.XML.Linq here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XLinq-XmlReader-and-1e17c0a5

Comment: Not as clean as using XPath but it got the job done so thanks!